# Squaring a logarithm when the base is a square root

Tags: logarithms

How is this equality obtained?

$$ 
-\log_\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}(x - 7) = \log_2 (x - 7)^2
$$

I understand the process until this point

$$ 
\log _\sqrt 2 (x-7) .
$$

How do I get from there to

$$
\log_2 (x - 7)^2
 ?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the formula:

1) $$\frac 1{\sqrt2}=2^{-\frac12}$$

2) $$\log_{a^p}b=\frac1p\log_ab$$

3) $$k\log_{a}b=\log_ab^k$$

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> Your claim is **false**, for example try $x = 6$.

$\log_2( (6 - 7)^2 ) = \log_2 (1) = 0$.

But $-\log_\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}(6 - 7) = -\log_\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}(-1)$ is not a real number (even no matter which branch cut).

> The claim is only true for **certain values of $x$**, such as real $x > 7$.

Do take a look and see whether the properties of logarithms you were taught were correctly stated or not (the conditions are very very important!).

> 1. $\log_a(bc) = \log_a(b) \log_a(c)$ for any positive reals $a,b,c$ such that $a \ne 1$.
>
>    a. This is false for $b,c < 0$.
>
>    b. This is meaningless for $a = 1$ or $b = 0$ or $c = 0$.
> 2. $\log_a(b^c) = c \log_a(b)$ for any positive reals $a,b$ and real $c$ such that $a \ne 1$.
>
>    a. This is false for $b < 0$.
>
>    b. This is meaningless for $a = 1$ or $b = 0$.
> 3. $\log_a(c) = \dfrac{\log_b(c)}{\log_b(a)}$ for any positive reals $a,b,c$ such that $a,b \ne 1$.
>
>    a. This can be extended for $c < 0$ (if we allow complex numbers).
>
>    b. But this is still meaningless for $a = 1$ or $b = 1$ or $c = 0$.

Let's see the correct claim and the proof:

> $-\log_\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}(x - 7) = \log_2( (x - 7)^2 )$ for any real $x > 7$.

Proof:

Take any real $x > 7$.

$\log_\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}(x-7) = \dfrac{\log_2(x-7)}{\log_2(\frac1{\sqrt{2}})}$   [by property (3)]

$\ = \dfrac{\log_2(x-7)}{\log_2(1)-\log_2(\sqrt{2})}$   [by property (1)]

$\ = -\dfrac{\log_2(x-7)}{\log_2(2^{\frac12})}$

$\ = -\dfrac{\log_2(x-7)}{\frac12\log_2(2)}$   [by property (2)]

$\ = -2\log_2(x-7)$

$\ = -\log_2((x-7)^2)$.   [by property (2)]

Note that in all steps the conditions for the properties of logarithms hold! The crucial step that fails if $x < 7$ is the last step, even if complex-valued logarithms are allowed. If (like in high-school) complex-valued logarithms are not allowed, then the very first step is already illegal because "$\log_\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}(x-7)$" is meaningless.

Comment: Conditions were never the part of the question. Your post is irrelevant. I know how to work out conditions, I had a difficulty understanding how would one transfer equation in a way I have explained.

Comment: @Fiste: If you say that my post is irrelevant, you're basically saying that **all mathematics** is irrelevant. If that is your **opinion**, fine, but it is **wrong** in mathematics. Mathematics is not about making **false** statements. "$\log_{\sqrt{2}}(x-7) = \log_2((x-7)^2)$" is a **false or meaningless** statement.

Comment: @Fiste: In case you don't understand my above comment, in real mathematics you are **not allowed** to perform arbitrary symbolic manipulation **unless** they are justified. Don't think that you can "manipulate first and work out conditions later". That may give you the right answer for very basic arithmetic but not for real mathematics. So if your goal is to get away from mathematics as fast as possible, then yes my post is not for you. But I hope that you'll realize that mathematics is not about mindless symbol manipulation but about one way to grasp **truth**.

Comment: You are blowing it way out of proportion. I asked a simple question, check out the preferred answer I have selected, that is EXACTLY what I was looking for. 
I understand very well what you were saying in your answer, it's simply not what I asked for.

Comment: My point is precisely that I am sure that what you're asking for is not enough if you want to learn real mathematics. Logical correctness is absolutely crucial beyond high-school mathematics, which is not really mathematics at all. You clearly don't appreciate it now, but you should later. If you've seen enough questions on Math SE about difficulty in understanding concepts, you would've seen that most of them are due to a weak or non-existent grasp of logic. The problem is that people who do not grasp logic are **rarely aware** of that issue until they finally learn logic properly.

Answer (score -1):

$$-\log_{1/\sqrt2}(x-7)=-\dfrac{\log(x-7)}{\log(1/\sqrt2)}=-\dfrac{\log(x-7)}{\log(2^{-1/2})}=2\dfrac{\log(x-7)}{\log2}=?$$

See [Properties of Logarithm](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Laws_of_Logarithms)